# Rails Drag And Drop For Create/Edit Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to search for an answer for this, but nothing seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm using Rails 4 and I have an Exercise model and a Routine model that have a has_many through relationship via Exercise_Routine. The users have associated with them a list of routines and a list of exercises. The goal is to let a user make up the associations of what exercises belong in routines by being able to drag them from their list of exercises to a list of exercises associated with the routine they're editing. 
So it would involve two lists. One being the list of exercises a user has and the other being the list of exercises associated with the current routine. I want to make it so they can drag and drop from either list to edit this or even for the initial creation.

I can get the drag and drop between lists to work. What confuses me is how to do the updating of the database with the changes. Would rails realize that the user just removed one thing from the list and that it should delete that record? Would it try and recreate all the associations in the list every time resulting in an error?

I would also have this happen as part of the edit action inside the routine controller since that is where it logically would make sense to do it. Also would it be better to do an AJAX call that does the update each time they make a change or wait for all the changes and a submit button press to do the actual update?

I can see how I want this to work in my head, but the how is eluding me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rails cannot do drag and drop by itself: you need to use some kind of Javascript library like jQuery.

There is a railscast on this topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised?view=comments